# How to check a member variable with py.test skipif?

Tags: python, pytest

In my `setUp` function in a TestCase I set a member variable `is_type` to True or False. I have a few tests in the class which shouldn't be run if the value is false. I don't know how to do this with the `skipif` functionality.

```
@py.test.mark.skipif( not ???.is_type )
def test_method(self):
   ...
```

`self` doesn't work for `???` since it's not in the object yet.  How can I refer to the `is_type` variable?

---

More complete example:

```
class DBTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.is_dynamo = os.environ.get( 'TEST_DB', '' ) == 'Dynamo'

    def test_account_ts(self):
        if not self.is_dynamo:
            return

        ...
```

How can I transform that `if not self.is_dynamo` into a py.test skipif condition instead?

Comment: It looks like you're using unittest.TestCase with py.test. Any reason for this? Can you give us a bit more code, or some example tests you want to have run?

Comment: The unittest is just remnants of how it used to be done. I'm okay with dropping that dependency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you mention, you can't refer to an instance in your `skipif` marker, since the instance doesn't exist yet.

I would keep it simple and do something like:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif(os.environ.get('TEST_DB') != 'Dynamo')
def test_dynamo():
    db = MyDatabaseWithDynamo(is_dynamo=True)
    # Some assertion or other.
```

You can use `@pytest.mark.skipif` on classes too.

The [documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html#skip-all-test-functions-of-a-class-or-module) on this feature has some good examples. Many of them relate to checking parts of the environment to decide what tests should get skipped. This sounds very similar to your use case, so I would say you are in good company.

But if, as you say in your comment below, you want to avoid global variables, you can raise a `pytest.skip` exception from wherever you want. Below I'm doing it in a fixture, which I think keeps test setup well-separated from test cases. See [the documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/builtin.html#raising-a-specific-test-outcome) for more possibilities.

Here is my test file:

```
import os
import pytest

class MyDatabaseWithDynamo(object):
    def __init__(self, is_dynamo):
        pass

@pytest.fixture
def database():
    is_dynamo = os.environ.get('TEST_DB') == 'Dynamo'
    if not is_dynamo:
        raise pytest.skip()
    return MyDatabaseWithDynamo(is_dynamo=True)

def test_db(database):
    pass
```

Here is the test output:

```
$ py.test test_foo.py
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.5 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
collected 1 items

test_foo.py s

==================================== 1 skipped in 0.01 seconds ===================================
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid referencing a global variable again since the conditions in the constructor aren't always trivial.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you want a little better. Let me take another stab at it.

Comment: `pytest.skip` may be what I'm looking for. I'll try it out.

Comment: just a headsup if seeing this in 2023 like me: you need to specify a reason or it fails with an error. E.g. `@pytest.mark.skipif(os.environ.get('TEST_DB') != 'Dynamo', reason='TEST_DB needs to be set to Dynamo to run this test')`

Answer (score 3):

```
import unittest
import functools


def skipIfNotDynamo(test_method):
    @functools.wraps(test_method)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not self.is_dynamo:
            raise unittest.SkipTest("Skip because it is not dynamo")

        return test_method(self)

    return wrapper


class DBTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.is_dynamo = ...

    @skipIfNotDynamo        
    def test_account_ts(self):
        ...
```