# How to write complex `pytest` skip decorators?

Tags: python, oop, testing, pytest, decorator

From the docs, it seems like the intended way to write skip decorators (that you'd import from e.g. `conftest.py`) is to use `skipif` (https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/skipping.html#id1). However, the condition shown in the example is simple and doesn't need to interact with any other parametrizations. Is it possible to get `skipif` to work when you also need to inspect arguments as part of the condition to skip?

In https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4a6db1500dc62870865fe7827524abd332a88fd9/scipy/conftest.py#L147-L180, we have decorators which perform the skips we want correctly, however, (IIUC) because we use `skip` rather than `skipif`, when we use `-rsx`, the skips are reported as coming from `conftest.py`, e.g. `SKIPPED [27] scipy/conftest.py:159: is_isomorphic only supports NumPy backend`. Is there a way to write the decorators such that the skips are reported from the test in which they originate?

We can recover that information from `--verbose` instead, but it would be much easier if this worked with `-rsx`. Cheers!

```py
# conftest.py
array_api_compatible = pytest.mark.parametrize("xp", xp_available_backends.values())

def skip_if_array_api_gpu(func):
    reason = "do not run with Array API on and not on CPU"
    # method gets there as a function so we cannot use inspect.ismethod
    if '.' in func.__qualname__:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            xp = kwargs["xp"]
            if SCIPY_ARRAY_API and SCIPY_DEVICE != 'cpu':
                if xp.__name__ == 'cupy':
                    pytest.skip(reason=reason)
                elif xp.__name__ == 'torch':
                    if 'cpu' not in torch.empty(0).device.type:
                        pytest.skip(reason=reason)
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # ditto
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

```
# example test
@skip_if_array_api_gpu
@array_api_compatible
def test_xxx(xp):
   ...
```

x-ref https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/discussions/11726

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603562/how-to-check-a-member-variable-with-py-test-skipif) help at all?

Comment: @quamrana unfortunately not - if the condition was solely based on the environment, that would work. In my case, the condition is based on both the environment and arguments of the test function/method.

Comment: But the second answer looks into the test object. Surely that's just the same as looking into `**kwargs` as you do?

Comment: @quamrana the second answer uses `unittest` not `pytest`. The equivalent for `pytest` is what I currently have - the skipping works fine with `pytest.skip`, but the report received by passing `-rsx` does not map back to the test function/method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a fixture and a marker:

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.addinivalue_line("markers",
        "skip_if_array_api(*backends, reasons=None, np_only=False, cpu_only=False): "
        "mark the desired skip configuration for the `skip_if_array_api` fixture.")

@pytest.fixture
def skip_if_array_api(xp, request):
    if "skip_if_array_api" not in request.keywords:
        return
    backends = request.keywords["skip_if_array_api"].args
    kwargs = request.keywords["skip_if_array_api"].kwargs
    np_only = kwargs.get("np_only", False)
    cpu_only = kwargs.get("cpu_only", False)
    if np_only:
        reasons = kwargs.get("reasons", ["do not run with non-NumPy backends."])
        reason = reasons[0]
        if xp.__name__ != 'numpy':
            pytest.skip(reason=reason)
        return
    if cpu_only:
        reason = "do not run with `SCIPY_ARRAY_API` set and not on CPU"
        if SCIPY_ARRAY_API and SCIPY_DEVICE != 'cpu':
            if xp.__name__ == 'cupy':
                pytest.skip(reason=reason)
            elif xp.__name__ == 'torch':
                if 'cpu' not in torch.empty(0).device.type:
                    pytest.skip(reason=reason)
    if backends is not None:
        reasons = kwargs.get("reasons", False)
        for i, backend in enumerate(backends):
            if xp.__name__ == backend:
                if not reasons:
                    reason = f"do not run with array API backend: {backend}"
                else:
                    reason = reasons[i]
                pytest.skip(reason=reason)
```

Each test then needs the `pytest.mark.usefixtures("skip_if_array_api")` decorator, along with the `pytest.mark.skip_if_array_api(...)` decorator to choose the options. It would be nice to have just a single decorator rather than the two, but verbosity can be kept low by applying the first decorator to every test in a module using `pytestmark` = pytest.mark.usefixtures("skip_if_array_api")`.

Comment: Hi lucascolley, welcome to SO. Link-only answers are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please consider updating your answer with your excellent code so that your answer is self-contained. Link-only answers are often flagged as 'low quality' and can become subject to deletion as a result. Thanks

Comment: okay, edit made!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample test which shows that `skipif` only skips due to a global condition, but you can generate your own skip wrapper which detects some condition and either goes ahead with the test anyway, or raises `skip()` which reports the test as skipped.

```py
import pytest
from pytest import skip
import functools

global_int = 2


def skipIfNotDynamic(test_method):
    @functools.wraps(test_method)
    def wrapper(self, **kwargs):
        xp = kwargs["xp"]
        if not xp:
            raise skip(f"Skip because xp is Falsey during {test_method.__name__}")

        return test_method(self, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


array_api_compatible = pytest.mark.parametrize('xp', [1, 2, 0, 3])


class TestGroup:
    @pytest.mark.skipif(global_int == 2, reason='global control')
    def test_something(self):
        assert True == False  # add assertion here

    @skipIfNotDynamic
    @array_api_compatible
    def test_else(self, xp):
        assert xp == 0, "test_else"
```

Output:

```
F:\...>pytest -rsx soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: F:\...
collected 5 items

soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py sFFsF                                                                              [100%]

====================================================== FAILURES =======================================================
_______________________________________________ TestGroup.test_else[1] ________________________________________________

self = <soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.TestGroup object at 0x0000020F489545D0>, xp = 1

    @skipIfNotDynamic
    @array_api_compatible
    def test_else(self, xp):
>       assert xp == 0, "test_else"
E       AssertionError: test_else
E       assert 1 == 0

soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py:32: AssertionError
_______________________________________________ TestGroup.test_else[2] ________________________________________________

self = <soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.TestGroup object at 0x0000020F48954B10>, xp = 2

    @skipIfNotDynamic
    @array_api_compatible
    def test_else(self, xp):
>       assert xp == 0, "test_else"
E       AssertionError: test_else
E       assert 2 == 0

soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py:32: AssertionError
_______________________________________________ TestGroup.test_else[3] ________________________________________________

self = <soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.TestGroup object at 0x0000020F48920E90>, xp = 3

    @skipIfNotDynamic
    @array_api_compatible
    def test_else(self, xp):
>       assert xp == 0, "test_else"
E       AssertionError: test_else
E       assert 3 == 0

soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py:32: AssertionError
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
SKIPPED [1] soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py:25: global control
SKIPPED [1] soFunctionsEmulatingSkipif.py:14: Skip because xp is Falsey during test_else
============================================ 3 failed, 2 skipped in 0.80s =============================================
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that in the summary, the fail comes from `sofunctionsemulatingskipif.py:14:`, which maps to the skip in the decorator. I want to be able to see which test functions (at least which line numbers they are at) fail in this summary.